# How to show months if it has no record and force it to zero if null on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have an orders table, and i need to fetch the orders record by month. but i have terms if there is no data in a month it should still show the data but forcing to zero like this:

[image]

what i have done is using my query:

```
select sum(total) as total_orders, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M") as date 
from orders 
where is_active = 1
AND tenant_id = 2
AND created_at like '%2021%'
group by DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m")
```

but the result is only fetched the existed data:

[image]

can anyone here help me to create the exactly query?

Thank you so much

Comment: Please share your table structure with sample data in text format instead of image.

Comment: total_orders month
298806606 january
501341444 february
308938113 march
546643759 april
86412240 may
8043180 june
0 july
0 august
0 september
0 october
0 november
0 december

Comment: This is the result after your select query. I need exact table structure with sample data.

Comment: What is exact MySQL version?

Comment: thanks all finally got my answers, its just using union an aliasing

Comment: Generate a range of months and do left join of this table to the aggregated results.

Comment: Can you post an answer for your "union an aliasing" method @RamadhaniBaharzah ? I'm interested to know, thanks.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for the answers & comments i really appreciate it.

i solved it by create table helper for static months then use union and aliasing, since i need the months in indonesia, i create case-when function too.

so, the query is like this:

```
SELECT total_orders,
       (CASE date WHEN 01 THEN 'Januari'
                  WHEN 02 THEN 'Februari'
                  WHEN 03 THEN 'Maret'
                  WHEN 04 THEN 'April'
                  WHEN 05 THEN 'Mei'
                  WHEN 06 THEN 'Juni'
                  WHEN 07 THEN 'Juli'
                  WHEN 08 THEN 'Agustus'
                  WHEN 09 THEN 'September'
                  WHEN 10 THEN 'Oktober'
                  WHEN 11 THEN 'November'
                  WHEN 12 THEN 'Desember'
                  ELSE date END                    ) AS date
FROM (SELECT SUM(total)                    AS total_orders, 
             DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m") AS date 
      FROM orders 
      WHERE is_active = 1
        AND tenant_id = 2
        AND created_at like '%2021%'
      GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m")

      UNION

      SELECT 0    AS total_orders, 
             code AS date
      FROM quantum_default_months             ) as Q
GROUP BY date
```

I still don't know if this query is fully correct or not, but I get my exact result.

[image]

cmiiw.
thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're trying to use a value that doesn't  exist in the table, one option is to use a **reference**; whether it's from a table or a query-generated value.

I'm guessing that in terms of date data, the column `created_at` in table `orders` may have a complete list all the 12 months in a year regardless of which year.

Let's assume that the table data for `orders` spans from 2019 to present date. With that you can simply create a 12 months reference table for a `LEFT JOIN` operation. So:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(created_at) mnt FROM orders GROUP BY MONTHNAME(created_at);
```

You can append that into your query like:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(total),0) as total_orders, mnt
from (SELECT MONTHNAME(created_at) mnt FROM orders GROUP BY MONTHNAME(created_at)) mn 
LEFT JOIN orders o
ON mn.mnt=MONTHNAME(created_at)
AND is_active = 1
AND tenant_id = 2
AND created_at like '%2021%'
GROUP BY mnt;
```

Apart from adding the 12 months sub-query and a `LEFT JOIN`, there are 3 other changes from your original query:

1. `IFNULL()` is added to the `SUM()` operation in `SELECT` to return `0` if the value is non-existent.
2. All the `WHERE` conditions has been switched to `ON` since remaining it as `WHERE` will make the `LEFT JOIN` becoming a normal `JOIN`.
3. `GROUP BY` is using the sub-query generated month (`mnt`) value instead.

Taking consideration of table `orders` might not have the full 12 months, you can generate it from query. There are a lot of ways of doing it but here I'm only going to show the `UNION` method that works with most MySQL version.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR(NOW()),mnt,'01')) dt
FROM
(SELECT 1 AS mnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION 
SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION 
SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) mn
```

If you're using MariaDB version that supports [SEQUENCE ENGINE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/), the same query above is much shorter:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(CONCAT_WS('-',YEAR(NOW()),mnt,'01'))
FROM (SELECT seq AS mnt FROM seq_1_to_12) mn
```

I'm using MariaDB 10.5 in [this demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=93bd194cd00e26e8f2a4b4471bf683ef) however it seems like the month name ordering is based on the name value rather than the month itself so it looks un-ordered. It's in the correct order if it's in [MySQL 8.0 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=382a351ef59443b6c98fde1dfcbaa22b) though.

Comment: "I'm using MariaDB 10.5 in this demo fiddle however it seems like the month name ordering ...... looks un-ordered. It's in the correct order ... in MySQL 8.0 fiddle though."   SQL does only return results in a specific order when `ORDER BY` is specified....

Comment: Got it @Luuk . I just realize that in the MariaDB fiddle, the custom 'month-generated' query is according to January - December ordering white the query that I extracted months from `orders` table is ordered by month name alphabet. When I change `.. GROUP BY MONTHNAME(created_at);` to `.. GROUP BY MONTH(created_at);`, the ordering change to January - December.